# Adding object in nested array

Tags: typescript, angular12

I am working on Angular 12 project where i have to add and remove the data from existing dataset.

I have a portal object in which i have PortalUser array and each PortalUser object has an array of Password (the structure is in below code snippet).

**Situation:** I have buttons to add user in user-array and add password in user's password-array.

**Requirement:** 1. When i click Add User it adds a user in the user-array (working fine) 2. When i click Add Password in 1st user (user at index 0), it should add password only in user at index 0 (Not working)

**Issue:** When i click Add Password in 1st user (user at index 0, addPassword(0)), it is adding password to all the users irrespective of index.

Please review code below and help me finding out what i am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

HTML Below

```
<p>{{ portal | json }}</p>

<hr>
<hr>
<a (click)="addUsername()">Add User</a><br>

<hr>
<a (click)="addPassword(0)">Add Password in 1st user</a><br>

<hr>
<a (click)="addPassword(1)">Add Password in 2nd user</a><br>
```

TS below

```
const emptyPassword = {
  "password": '',
  "id": 0
};

const emptyPortalUser = {
  "username": '',
  "id": 0,
  "passwords": [emptyPassword]
};

@Component({
  selector: 'logic-poc',
  templateUrl: './logic-poc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logic-poc.component.css']
})
export class LogicPocComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  portal = {
    "id": 0,
    "name": '',
    "users": [emptyPortalUser],
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  addUsername() {
    this.portal.users.push(emptyPortalUser);
  }

  addPassword(ui: number){
    this.portal.users[ui].passwords.push(emptyPassword);    
  }

}
```

Expected Output

```
{
   "id": 0,
   "name": "",
   "users": [
      {
         "username": "",
         "id": 0,
         "passwords": [
            {
               "password": "",
               "id": 0
            },
            {
               "password": "",
               "id": 0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "username": "",
         "id": 0,
         "passwords": [
            {
               "password": "",
               "id": 0
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Actual output I am getting

```
{
   "id": 0,
   "name": "",
   "users": [
      {
         "username": "",
         "id": 0,
         "passwords": [
            {
               "password": "",
               "id": 0
            },
            {
               "password": "",
               "id": 0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "username": "",
         "id": 0,
         "passwords": [
            {
               "password": "",
               "id": 0
            },
            {
               "password": "",
               "id": 0
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You push same user object to the users array.
You need to push different user instances.

What follows is that in addUsername() function, a new user needs to be created.

Comment: Thanks Lesiak, It worked.

I used below code for this in addUsername() function

this.portal.users.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emptyPortalUser)));

Comment: This is really convoluted way of creating new object. I would either create a function `makeNewEmptyUser` or simply move the emptyPortalUser (and emptyPassword) inside addUsername()